# Is there any kind of practice dummy somewhere that I can test skills on?

Tags: diablo-iii

Some games have practice dummies (or suitable alternatives) that players can test skills or dps on.

Is there anything similar in Diablo III that I can hit repeatedly without killing to test skills and/or dps on?

Comment: Unkillable mobs, etc, count?  If you do find something yourself, make sure you post it as an answer because I'm interested as well.

Comment: @dlanod I did find something that worked for what I was testing, and posted it as an answer below. I'm still in Act 3 though, so there might be a better mob somewhere else

Answer (score 2):

Since bosses and mobs are easily accessible and deaths are of little consequence (in terms of cost to you, including the time required to get to where you were at the time of the death) in Diablo 3, a practice dummy would not have made much sense. It's much easier to just try out different skill combos on actual monsters and bosses.

So the answer is **no**, there is no such thing in Diablo 3.

Comment: Thanks, I figured that would be the case but thought I'd double check. I wanted to do some tests with a skill to answer [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/66307/8462), and just ended up testing on regular mobs. I'm in ActIII right now, and found those big things in the Keep Depths that turtle up make fairly good test subjects (forget what they're called).

Comment: Oh, and I'd rather test without dying thanks :) It's easier to figure out averages if you're not always dying, and is much faster

Answer (score 2):

Well there doesn't appear to be any practice dummies, but so far I'm finding the **Demonic Tremors** in the **Keep Depths** of **Act III** to work fairly well.

They've got a lot of of hp, and will curl up in a defensive ball which makes them take very little damage. In addition, there are two waypoints to get down there, so its fairly easy to find some.

Of course, I haven't gone past Act III yet, so if I find a better test subject I'll update this answer :)