# How is damage calculated for Way of the Hundred Fists?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-monk

The Monk's `Way of the Hundred Fists` ability comes with a base tag of `140% weapon damage`. Simple enough, but the skill in itself is composed of seven punches.

Again, simple enough, but then, the damage counts of each hit is a bit different (easily visible if you have damage amounts shown). It acts like `HIGH - LOW x 5 - HIGH` as far as damage is concerned.

I'm not too well versed with Diablo 3's damage calcs (am just trying to enjoy the game with an easy N/NM run right now), so just being curious.

How is the damage calculated for WotHF? Provided I have a base damage of 1500, I'd assume that WotHF is ~2100 damage.

Is that in total (i.e. `700 + 140 x 5 + 700`), or each hit tier (i.e. `2100 + 700 x 5 + 2100`), or some other gleeful calculation (i.e. `1050 + random x 5 + 1050` or something)?

Answer (score 2):

[Way of the Hundred Fists](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/class/monk/active/way-of-the-hundred-fists) consists of 3 attacks, which appear to be 1 hit, 5 fast hits, than 1 hit again. For most purposes ([such as on-hit effects](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/67504/8462)), the 5 fast hits count as 1 hit.

The three attacks each seem to do 1/3 of 140% weapon damage each, so your first and last hit are around 46.6% weapon damage, while your 5-hit combo is around 9.3% weapon damage per hit.

Answer (score 2):

Each **attack** does a total of 140% weapon damage.  The second attack of [WoTHF](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/class/monk/active/way-of-the-hundred-fists) consists of multiple **hits**.  The 140% damage is divided among those hits.  If you turn on damage numbers, you can see that the first attack does ~140% weapons damage, the second atack does a series of smaller amounts, and the final attack goes back to 140%.

So a default WotHF 3 attack combo would go:

- one 140% strike
- five 28% strikes
- one 140% strike